# Howto find out if Laravel Command has been started via the scheduler?

Tags: laravel, command, command-line-interface, scheduler

When the laravel scheduler starts a command like:

`$schedule->command('test:testcommand')->hourly();`

i need to find out, inside the command, if it has been started via

`artisan test:testcommand`
or
`artisan schedule:run`

i looked into `$_SERVER['argv']` but i don´t see any info that helps me to
identify this.
maybe laravel has some fancy internal functions, but i wasn´t able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to communicate through arguments. So you could do as follows:

```
$schedule->command('test:testcommand',['--scheduler'])->hourly();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with events:

`php artisan make:event OnCommandRun`

Then in the `handle()` of your `testcommand` class fire it:

`event(new OnCommandRun());`

Then within the event `handle()` function do whatever you want

[More on Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#introduction)

Comment: I believe this event will be called anyway, doesn't matter if the command gets called directly or by scheduler - this event wouldn't make sense if only one way would trigger it. So how should this event help me here to identify who called the command?

Comment: sorry i didn't notice at first the purpose is testing